# leftBarButtonItem is NULL

Tags: ios, null, uinavigationitem, nsnull

running into a weird issue

I have a condition that checks whether a leftBarButtonItem exists and performs an action based on that.

So my check is simple:

```
  if (!self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem)
```

However, I am running into a situation where the leftBarButtonItem does not exist, but it is also not nill. It is (null).

And the way I find that out is by printing it out:

```
  NSLog(@"left nav button %@", self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem);
```

Read:

```
  left nav button (null)
```

How can you check whether it is NULL since the nil check is not working?

I have tried checking against [NSNull null],  isKindOfClass: NSNull Class, == NULL, == NSNull null, (NSNull *) self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem == [NSNull null]

I even tried to make a string with leftBarButton's description and check that for null. No go.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `[[NSNull null] isEqual:self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem]`?

Comment: Do you have a small test case? Which iOS version?